Not able to take screenshots with python, if the python app is run in background
What I try to do is to make a python app that takes screenshots of a game in short intervals and check if a round in the game has ended.
My script is working so far as that I am able to take screenshots and parse them, but as soon as I put the game window in the foreground and the terminal in the background no screenshot is taken anymore. Only if i Alt+Tab back to the terminal screenshots work again.
Additional Info: System is Windows 11
I already tried Pillow, mss and win32ui to take screenshots, but the problem persists with all of them.
I also disabled "Quick Edit Mode" in windows terminal.
Using mss
import time
from mss.windows import MSS as mss

with mss() as sct:
    while True:
        sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[0])
        im = Image.frombytes("RGB", sct_img.size, sct_img.bgra, "raw", "BGRX")
        time.sleep(1.0)

Using Pillow
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

while True:
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,w,h))
    time.sleep(1.0)

Using win32ui
    import win32gui
    import win32ui
    from PIL import Image

    hwnd_target = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Backpack Battles')

    left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd_target)
    w = right - left
    h = bot - top

    hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
    mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()


    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

    im = Image.frombuffer(
        'RGB',
        (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
        bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)


Are you using an IDE to run the code or just a file? I had a problem with VS code it stopped running something when I minimized it.

I tried this and it still made screen shots even when I minimized the shell.
    import cv2 as cv
    import pyautogui
    import numpy as np
    import time
    
    i=0
    while True:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        screenshot = cv.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        print(screenshot,i,i,i,i,i,i,i)



As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
